# Does Mysql 5 have procedures for managing hierarchical data?

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I use nested set model for saving [hierarchical data](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) into database table and I'm interested in if MySQL has built-in support for adding/deleting nodes or I have to write stored procedures from scratch.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge MySQL does not have an inbuilt function to do this. You may have to implement your own solution.

I have implemented nested sets with stored procedures and it worked well. I believe there has been further work on the Nested Set principle with [Nested intervals](http://www.sigmod.org/sigmod/record/issues/0506/p47-article-tropashko.pdf) to address the issues regarding the high number of updates required on the insertion or deletion of a node - but this too has its own set of problems.

Answer (score 0):

as @teabot says, MySQL doesn't ship with any inbuilt functionality to do this.  However, a number of sources exist which will give you more than a half decent starting point for the queries you require, so you want have to entirely roll your own.

For examples, see [Working with Graphs in MySQL](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html#nested_set_model) , the [MySQL docs](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) and maybe even [Joe Celko's book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hierarchies-Smarties-Kaufmann-Management-Systems/dp/1558609202).  Depending on your exact use case, you might also find that someone has done it for you (see [django-mptt](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/) implementation).