# How to Change a Node, Python - Networkx

Tags: python, networkx, immutability

I am planning a graph.  I would like to build a simplified graph.  Then expand it.  This expansion will include changing some of the nodes in to other graphs.  Since a dictionary key is immutable, are there ways to change the node from one object type to another?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to make a new graph whose edges have the data type that you're after. For example, consider the following.

```
G = nx.path_graph(5) # graph with edges [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
G_new = nx.Graph()
for a,b in G.edges:
    G_new.add_edge(float(a),float(b))
```

The graph G_new has edges `[(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 2.0), (2.0, 3.0), (3.0, 4.0)]`.

Comment: Ben,

Thank you for great concept and example.  This is a complete new graph so the old graph still exists - version control. A new graph could have a unique name, and copied to generic name to more easily reuse code.  The version history would then have a copy of the generating code and the resultant graph.

The version history will grow due to code and graph.  Is there a trade off of storing each version of the graph versus storing the code for generating it? A trade off is storage vs computational time.

Might there be a way to manage versioning as capturing differences some how?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're getting at here with "version history" and "versioning"; why would you be modifying both versions of the graph at the same time? I'd have a better chance of understanding what you're getting at if you could be specific about your usage case. For what it's worth, I see this process as basically analogous to the numpy [astype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) method.

Comment: Ben,  I see that my presentation was not clear as to what was changing.  The intent was to  indicate that the collection of versions change over time rather than changing older versions.

Comment: Ben,  I see that my presentation was not clear as to what was changing.  The intent was to  indicate that the collection of versions change over time rather than changing older versions.  The astype reference shows how to change a type, but that would seem to be a mutation which would corrupt the graph.  

This discussion indicates I need to better define what I mean by version control:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060645/graphs-and-version-control

As yet I have not found any examples or strategies for version control of graphs.