# Need help in creating dynamic menu

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, menu

I am developing a website using PHP and this is the 1st time I am trying a dynamic menu.

What I am doing is I have created a table for pages.

The table structure is as follows:

```
____________________________________________________________________________
|page_id|title|url|content|menu_title|show_on_navuigation|is_sub|parent_page|
|_______|_____|___|_______|__________|___________________|______|___________|
```

Here `is_sub` indicates whether it is a dropdown menu of some main menu. and `parent_page` is the main menu of the sub menu.

Now, what I want is, like

I have created 2 parent pages:

`About Us` and `Test`

and  2 sub menu's: Test aboutus and testsub,

Test aboutus is sub of About Us and testsub is sub of test.

How actually should the query and the loop, so that the menu renders perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

This is my menu structure:

```
<ul>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About Us</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='corporateprofile'><span>Corporate Profile</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='visionandmission'><span>Vision &amp; Mission</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Business Services</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='recruitment'><span>Recruitment</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='training'><span>Training</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='executivesearch'><span>Executive Search</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='payroll'><span>Payroll</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='backgroundverification'><span>Background Verification</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Employers</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='enquiry'><span>Enquiry</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='jobdescription'><span>Job Description</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='employercontract'><span>Employer Contract</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='feedback'><span>Feedback</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='javascript:;'><span>Job Seeker</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='applyforjob'><span>Apply For Job/Register</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='careertips'><span>Career Tips</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='interview Questions'><span>Interview Questions</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='interviewprocess'><span>Interview Process</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='corporatedress'><span>Corporate Dress</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Franchise</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Franchise Enquiry Form</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact us</span></a></li> 

</ul>

<?php
function displayMenu($parent_page_id) {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `parent_page` = '$parent_page_id'"; // sql
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
      if( mysql_num_rows($result) === 0 ) { // mysql_num_rows() is deprecated, but you are using mysql extension so that's why I show it here
         return true; // exit function
      } // else, continue to rest of function
      echo '<ul>';
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // deprecated mysql php function here for simplicity
         echo '<li><a href="' . $result['url'] . '">' . $result['menu_title'] . '</a>'; // no closing </li> yet
         displayMenu($row['page_id']); // this is the recursive part
         echo '</li>'; // close the <li> from before the recursion
      }
      echo '</ul>';
}
$get_base_menu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE parent_page = 0");
while($fetch_base_menu = mysql_fetch_array($get_base_menu))
{
    $parent_page_id = $fetch_base_menu['page_id'];
    displayMenu($parent_page_id);

}
```

?>

Comment: Do you really want to do all this work with mysql for a menu? The menu is usually the same across the entire site and rarely changes. So it makes sense, I think, to just hard-code it in HTML. It only makes sense to put it in the database, I think, if you're going to be frequently changing it, AND if you are creating some kind of "backend" to give your end user a way to edit the menu structure.
Otherwise, why use a database for this?

Comment: Yes Buttle. The client wants an option to add more pages in future. So I had to create a table for the pages and menu

Comment: @ButtleButkus that's what I was thinking of. Usually menu items are usually the same except for maybe changing something login/logout and register/login.

Comment: Vishal, so your client might want to create any number of levels in the menu, to access different pages. But how will they create the pages? I assume that if they are going to handle the coding of new pages, they can handle adding some HTML to the menu "widget".

Comment: Buttle, I have created a form in the backend to be able to create pages.

Comment: I will give you some answer in a minute.

Comment: Ok Buttle. Waiting eagerly for the answer

Comment: Can you post what you want the HTML to look like, actually? E.g. is the dropdown using ul??

Comment: This is the static structure:

Comment: <ul>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About Us</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='corporateprofile'><span>Corporate Profile</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='visionandmission'><span>Vision &amp; Mission</span></a></li>
      </ul>

Comment: It wont allow me to comment more :(

Comment: That's fine. It will take me a few more minutes.

Comment: I have posted the menu structure in the question above

Comment: Ok Buttle. No Problem

Comment: Ok I posted a recursive function. Let me know if you need me to fill in the mysql query. I don't know what database interface you are using (like PDO or mysql_query), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest thing for you to code will be something like this recursive function. All you have to do is put it on your page and make sure you have `parent_page_id = 0` for the base level menu items. (I'm using `parent_page_id` instead of `parent_page` because I assume that is what you mean and it is more clear for the answer.)

Calling the function with an argument of "0" should give you the full menu tree.

```
$trace = array();

function displayMenu($parent_page_id) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_menu` WHERE `parent_page_id` = $parent_page_id"; // sql
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  if( mysql_num_rows($result) === 0 ) { // mysql_num_rows() is deprecated, but you are using mysql extension so that's why I show it here
     $trace[] = "Page_id $parent_page_id has no children";
     return true; // exit function
  } // else, continue to rest of function
  echo '<ul>';
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // deprecated mysql php function here for simplicity
     $trace[] = "Entered while loop for page_id = $parent_page_id"; // not an error, just tracking
     echo '<li><a href="' . $row['url'] . '">' . $row['menu_title'] . '</a>'; // no closing </li> yet
     displayMenu($row['page_id']); // this is the recursive part
     echo '</li>'; // close the <li> from before the recursion
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}

displayMenu(0); // call function for base level

var_dump($trace);
```

More info:

I have researched the topic before and had a nice link to a page on mysql.com with an in-depth exploration of hierarchical relational database structures. But when I checked, the link was broken!

But, I think I found it on another site, here:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Buttle I am using mysql_query

Comment: Buttle, I will try and get back to you if I have any queries. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I changed the code to use the mysql functions and I put in the actual mysql query, except I use `parent_page_id` instead of `parent_page` because that is more clear to other people.

Comment: Yes, ok Buttle. Wil try that

Comment: Hi Buttle, I have posted the query i have written in my question. Its not showing any output. I can see only html tags in view source, but no text inside the tags. Is it correct what I have written. Could you please let me know the changes if any

Comment: Ahh, Vishal, you should have caught my mistake. I had `$result['url']` and `$result['menu_tile']`. Fixed now. $row is the variable, not $result, there. I also added the $trace variable just to check things, before I realized what the error was.

Comment: Glad it worked. Hey, thanks for the checkmark! If you wouldn't mind giving me an upvote too, I wouldn't mind either!

Comment: I tried Buttle. But it wont allow me as I dont have enough reputation.Sorry for that

Comment: You are a genius. I wonder how long it muight take me to be a coder like this :)

Comment: Haha thanks for the compliment. I suppose if you spend a few hours a day, then maybe it will take you 1-2 years to become a genius too.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest trying to get away from using an Adjacency List model and move toward a much easier to manage solution, such as a nested set. Using an MPTT type solution should help you manage your hierarchical data much easier. Using an Adjacency List model you are limited at a certain point.

I'd suggest looking into using something along the lines of [Zebra_MPTT](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-mptt/), or some other form of MPTT library. Please checkout this article on [Managing Hierarchical data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

Comment: It looks like we have consensus about that Hillyer link.

Comment: Indeed :) There was another article I read awhile back but I'm having some trouble finding it now.

Comment: I had the above one in my bookmarks, but for some reason they removed it from mysql.com. Luckily, I was able to find it by googling the title saved in my google bookmarks.